# How can I debug EF? (analyze SQL queries)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How can I debug the Entity Framework? Can I see which queries it is actually trying to execute to the SQL server, to troubleshoot issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the MVC Mini Profiler: http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

It's very lightweight, doesn't intrude on your app, and is easily removed if need be. Plus, Stack Overflow uses it.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast your query to `ObjectQuery` and then use [`ObjectQuery.ToTraceString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx) - that returns the full SQL for your query. Alternatively of course you can simply use SQL Profiler on your database to see what SQL gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Entity Framework Profiler. http://efprof.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Monitoring tool from the Server to watch the queues directly.
For MSSQL Server see: http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2008/1/3/View-recently-run-queries-in-MSSQL-2005

Comment: Edited this whith the answer, what server are you using?