# Entity Framework seems to replace parameters with their actual values

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We're seeing a whole bunch of SQL errors in our logs about *Must declare the scalar variable "@"* or some such thing.  Tracing into the actual SQL that generates the error, it appears these are SQL statement that the Entity Framework generates.  Here's an example:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[AccountId] AS [AccountId], 
    [Extent1].[Username] AS [Username], 
    [Extent1].[EmployerId] AS [EmployerId], 
    [Extent1].[EmployeeId] AS [EmployeeId], 
    [Extent1].[SubscriberId] AS [SubscriberId], 
    [Extent1].[RelationshipCode] AS [RelationshipCode], 
    [Extent1].[AccountType] AS [AccountType], 
    [Extent1].[AccountStatus] AS [AccountStatus]
    FROM [dbo].[jc_Accounts] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (@'Brunswick' = [Extent1].[Username]) OR ((@'Brunswick' IS NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Username] IS NULL))
```

The thing causing the error is that @'Brunswick' line, which is supposed to be the Username we're looking for.  So, it's as if the Entity Framework is swapping @p0 or something with the actual value.  We're also seeing tons of errors about things like @2892734 or some such, so numeric parameters are also affected.  For example:

```
WHERE ([Extent4].[AreaLevel] = 2) AND ([Extent1].[DimensionId] = [Extent4].[AreaId]) AND ([Extent5].[GroupId] = @106929) AND ([Extent5].[IsActive] = 1) AND ([Extent5].[AreaId] = [Extent1].[DimensionId])
```

Unfortunately, our database context and entity repository code is something you'd see in your worst nightmare.  A lot of it hasn't been touched in years, there's wrappers around wrappers around wrappers, things that use reflection to map POCOs to stored procedure calls, all sorts of fun stuff.  We've spent a ton of time on this and we haven't found anything that can shed some light on this issue.

We've also upgraded Entity Framework from 4 to 5 to 6 and other versions in between, and this bug persists.  So I don't think it's a weird EF bug.

**My Question:**

In what case would EF generate such a query?  Or, if it's for sure some sort of custom thing we've *extended* the Entity Framework into doing, what sorts of extensions would I want to start looking at?  I'm looking for things I could search the code base for and get some clues.

I don't need a full answer, I'm looking for some ideas from EF experts to get me headed down the right track.  I can add more details, just ask below.

Comment: Can you provide example of your EF query?

Comment: As i understand you found this sql queries with SQL Server Profiler?

Comment: @zxxc - [SQL Server Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events)

Comment: I searched up and down the code base, and the only thing I can find that I believe would generate a query like that is the following: `return this.Accounts.Where(account => (string.Compare(userName, account.Username,true)==0)).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: But of course when I run that method manually (we actually have a functional test that does this) and attach the profiler, it generates the correct query.

Comment: how types of this.Accounts differs in this case? or maybe for test you are using different context?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6 source code :), or try to use microsoft pdb servers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627831/how-can-i-debug-ef-analyze-sql-queries. You can cast your query to ObjectQuery and then use ObjectQuery.ToTraceString()

Answer (score 1):

It's weird indeed. Even though you might not want to change your context, would it be reasonable to temporarily add some custom logging to it? Earlier today I happened to give that example in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684008/sql-profiling-entity-framework-queries-that-make-no-sense-and-i-cannot-find/43684959?noredirect=1#comment74421944_43684959) :

```
public MyContext : DbContext
{
    private static ILog log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public MyContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        this.Database.Log = (msg) => log.Trace(msg);
    }
}
```

However, **very** temporarily, and in debug if you can reproduce the query, you could do something like that to break when it happens then crawl up the callstack :

```
public MyContext : DbContext
{
    private static ILog log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public MyContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        this.Database.Log = (msg) => 
        {
            if (msg.Contains("@'Brunswick'"))
                Debugger.Break();
        };
    }
}
```

If you fancy regex, or if you don't always get the same variable substitution, you could make `msg` match against "@ that isn't followed by 'p__linq__'", but I'll leave that to you!

Comment: Yea, I was actually considering something along these lines..  It does seem to happen at least 4-5 times every hour, so we wouldn't have to have this on very long..  I think it only repros in production though, because, _of course_ it only ever repros in production.

Comment: Also, yea good idea about the regex to look for valid parameters..  Since this happens on all sorts of queries, not just that Brunswick one.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not mistaken, i already saw some of this
and it was situation where we used for example
`Take(20)` instead of `Take(()=>20)`

or another case is 
`var a = []{'a','b','c'}
var res = context.Users.Where(u=>a.contains(u.Id))`